# Fixing padding issues when using iframe css responsiveness trick

Tags: css, media-queries, responsiveness

Fixing padding issues when using iframe css responsiveness trick.

```
.videoWrap {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.videoWrap iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

People use this css trick in order to insure the iframe stays responsive while the video preserves its aspect ratio, but the problem is when you use a different value than 100%.

```
<div class="videoWrap">
   <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/xxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

I have an example below. And the issue is that depending on the device the margin between the video and the text becomes bigger, I want to keep the margin to a minimum, but it's hard to put a maximum value to the margin below of the video. Is there an easy way to do this? The only solution would be to use a lot of media query, but I only use 5 breakpoints on my website, I would have to use 9 or more to prevent the bottom margin from becoming too large.

Is there a better way around this issue?

https://codepen.io/codepen_user_123/pen/KKNmLad

Comment: `padding-bottom:56.25%;` is relative to the containing block.